# Can you do sums with a datetime in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know how to get the date:

```
from datetime import datetime
time = datetime.now()
print(time)
```

But is there a way where you can work out the days/hours until a certain date, maybe storing the date as an integer or something? Thx for all answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken your answer and developed it so that the user can enter the date that they want: Here it is

```
from datetime import datetime
year=int(input("What year?"))
month=int(input("What month?"))
day=int(input("What day?"))
hour=int(input("What hour?"))
minute=int(input("What minute?"))
second=int(input("What second?"))
then = datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)
now = datetime.now()
diff = then - now
print(diff)

print(diff.total_seconds())
```

Thanks you all for your answers :D

**Now Variable**

Here is even better code, you can just take out the now variable, and put it directly in the difference integer

---

```
from datetime import datetime
while True:
    inp = input("Enter date in format yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss")
    try:
        then = datetime.strptime(inp, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
diff = then - datetime.now()
print(diff, "until", inp)
print(diff.total_seconds(),"seconds")
```

Comment: You can do it with a single string, I will add it to my answer

Comment: from datetime import datetime


while True:
    inp = input("Enter date in format yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss")
    try:
        then = datetime.strptime(inp, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")

now = datetime.now()
diff = then - now
print(diff, "until", inp)
print(diff.total_seconds(),"seconds")

Answer (score 7):

Just create another datetime object and subtract which will give you a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
then = datetime(2016,1,1,0,0,0)
diff = then - now
print(diff)

print(diff.total_seconds())

15 days, 3:42:21.408581
1309365.968044
```

If you want to take user input:

```
from datetime import datetime


while True:
    inp = input("Enter date in format yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss")
    try:
        then = datetime.strptime(inp, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")

now = datetime.now()
diff = then - now
print(diff)
```

Demo:

```
$Enter date in format yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss2016/01/01 00:00:00
15 days, 3:04:51.960110
```

Comment: Thx, thought it might be something simple like that

Comment: Err, you forgot the links to the doc. :D

Comment: @BhargavRao,  I was only testing to see if you were online ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao, me or Padraic Cunningham

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil, me, that fella is always on my case!

Comment: Not you @JoeBeastlyGerbil, Padraic has a "history" of not adding links to the docs. :P

Comment: I thought today is the day to stop giving "fish" and start teaching "how to fish" .... :D

Comment: What are you guys talking about? :D

Comment: Lol, @JoeBeastlyGerbil follow Padraic for a few days and you'll get to know! All the best.